# Show just one pole in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [pole] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nazev_1] => Název_1_1
                    [nazev_2] => Název_1_2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [nazev_1] => Název_2_1
                    [nazev_2] => Název_2_2
                )
```

And I use this script for show data:

```
foreach ($everything as $innerArray) {

    if (is_array($innerArray)){

        foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to ask you, how can I show just values from [nazev_1].

Thank you!

Comment: `foreach ($everything['pole'] as $pole) echo $pole['nazev_1'];`...!?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do:

```
foreach ($everything as $innerArray) {
     if (is_array($innerArray) && !empty($innerArray['nazev_1'])){
         echo $innerArray['nazev_1'];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
foreach ($everything as $innerArray) { 
    if (is_array($innerArray)){ 
        foreach ($innerArray as $value) {
            echo $value['nazev_1'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Return only first letter of all values.

Comment: If you have only these two `nazev_1` and `nazev_2` then you can echo them separately like `echo $value['nazev_1'];` and `echo $value['nazev_2'];`